# importing groovy scripts from other scripts dynamically

Tags: groovy

I am trying to load 2 groovy scripts from a remote location (say S3). The first script is straight forward. It names a package a.b and the file itself is called c.dsl.

```
package a.b; 

int i = 10;  

public void anotherfunc() {}; 

private void anotheractivityFunc() { int k = 9;};
```

The second groovy script has the following code in it (it is named s.dsl)

```
package c.d; 

// Notice the import of the other script file here
import a.b.c; 

int i = 10;  

c myself; 

public void func() {}; 

private void activityFunc() 
{ 
    int k = 9; 
    c nbn;
};
```

This script is trying to create an object of the class defined in the first script. I run this through with this code

```
CustomClassLoader loader = new CustomClassLoader(GroovyDSLTest.class.getClassLoader(), configuration);
GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell(loader, configuration);
Script script = shell.parse(scriptText, "s.dsl");
```

CustomClassLoader is defined with this function

```
public Class loadClass(name, ...)
{
    try
    {
        return super.loadClass(name, lookupScriptFiles, preferClassOverScript, resolve);
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
        if (name.equals("a.b.c"))
            // Notice how I handle the import a.b.c from the second groovy file
            return parseClass(<text from c.dsl>, "c.dsl");
        throw e;
    }
}
```

I get a compile error when I do this. It loads the a.b.c file cleanly. But when I try to make a member variable "c" it fails.

```
s.dsl: 1: [Static type checking] - The variable [myself] is undeclared.
    @ line 8, column 3.
    c myself;
      ^

s.dsl: 1: [Static type checking] - Cannot find matching method c.d.s#c(java.lang.Object). Please check if the declared type is right and if the method exists.
@ line 8, column 1.
    c myself;
    ^
```

Why is it not able to find c? I was able to print the classloader as it loads classes and it did load a.b.c. Changing the above to use a.b.c instead of just "c" does not work as well. What is the name of the class that groovy generates from the script file. I want to be able to access this class and create objects of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grrrr... I figured this out.

a)  one needs to call in loadClass  setClassCacheEntry();

b)  Also naming a class "c" does not seem to work. I renamed it to MyClass and it seems to work

Answer (score 0):

How about using `@BaseScript`?

You can create a class that you want to import:

```
abstract class Something extends Script {
    ...
}
```

And `@BaseScript` can help you to import it: `@groovy.transform.BaseScript Something something`

See: http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.5.2/html/gapi/groovy/transform/BaseScript.html

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately, each of these is a separate domain language script with one calling the other, I dont control it in code. If I have a script A.groovy, from B.groovy I want to create A obj = new A(); obj.func1(); How do I accomplish this without specifying class A in A.groovy

Comment: Is the load class override the correct way to import dynamically and have I completely agree implemented everything by just calling parse class?